# Add numbers in an array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have made the two following insertions into my document. I have been trying to find a way to show the total number of domestic students and the total number of international students for
the recorded years for every university. I tried using $sum aggregating by using in $project stage but I just get the answer 0. I am also not sure whether it is adding all the domestic students from each year and adding all the international students from each year.

```
db.universities.insertMany([
{country: "Australia", city: "Melbourne", name: "SUT",
domestic_students : [
{ year: 2014, number: 24774 },
{ year: 2015, number: 23166 },
{ year: 2016, number: 21913 },
{ year: 2017, number: 21715}],
international_students : [
{ year: 2014, number: 32178 },
{ year: 2015, number: 36780 },
{ year: 2016, number: 67899 },
{ year: 2017, number: 65321 }]
 },
{country: "Australia", city: "Sydney", name: "UTS",
domestic_students : [
{ year: 2014, number: 67891 },
{ year: 2015, number: 56312 },
{ year: 2016, number: 45679 },
{ year: 2017, number: 71235}]
}
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sum over an array of numbers, but you can't sum over an array of subdocuments. For that you need [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

$unwind "explodes" the array into different documents (mid-aggregation). So if you do:

```
 $unwind: {
        path: '$domestic_students',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
    }
```

You'll end up with several documents that have a subdocument of domestic_student (not an array of subdocuments).

I think this does what you want:

```
db.universities.aggregate[{
    $unwind: {
        path: '$domestic_students',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: '$international_students',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: '$country',
        dtotal: {
            $sum: '$domestic_students.number'
        },
        itotal: {
            $sum: '$international_students.number'
        }
    }
}]
```

I like using MongoDB compass to help with aggregations, because I can see the stages and outcome from a sample:

[image: mongodb compass and stages]